# Raised bumps on my succulents

Tags: diagnosis

Recently I discovered these spots on some of my succulents. It had been raining heavily a week back, and now it's quite sunny. I haven't watered it since the rains fell. The spots are raised, and don't move. Some of the bumps have turned brown while some are just the color of the leaves. I thought they might be edema but not very sure. 
[image]

Comment: Can you scrape one off and look at it under magnification?

Comment: Did you accidentally get some chemical substance on it? That can cause similar spotting.

Comment: Can you give us a very up-close picture of one of the bumps.  Make sure there it plenty of light to make out the details of the bump.

Answer (score 1):

It does appear to be edema. The plant took more water than it could transpire, but not enough to cause overwatering rot.

Comment: You are correct.   I know this information, but for Menang Airbut is there any information you could elaborate on about edema.  Like is there a cure?  What can she/he do to prevent this from happening in the future.  Just a little more information to educate everyone reading your post.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to my succulent too. I did some research online, and it looks like it might be due to mealy bugs (those tiny little gnats). Spraying rubbing alcohol on the plant will kill the bugs and not harm the plant.

Comment: Seeing possible evidence about bugs is no reason to spray.  You need to see them to spray.   Even something as safe as alcohol can damage the plant if applied incorrectly.  What strength is safe?  How often is it safe to spray?